# How to use CSS to override table styles in HTML files created by Word

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am learning HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to work on a project for modifying HTML documents that were created from the Word "Save As" function.  I want to be able to use Word to save a document as a "Web Page, Filtered".  The ultimate goal that I am working towards is to be able to use CSS to standardize  HTML documents that were originally created in Microsoft Word.

Future notes: eventually, I would like to be able to use JavaScript (seems like the best option for now) to be able to apply different formats based the number of columns in the table.  I will also be affecting the indent of the tables (I am thinking that this might be able to be done through margin on the table.  I would also like to be able to add some tags around the beginning of the body to insert standardized formatting for stuff like menus, a stationary header, and probably some over features.

I got a long way to go but taking baby steps towards the final results.

Below is the HTML code that was created by Word for the tables only.  I made slight modifications to it because I plan on using an external CSS file and I work on a process to remove the header styles.

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 
   style='border-collapse:collapse'>
   <tr>
      <td width=67 valign=top style='width:.7in;border:solid 
         windowtext 
         1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
         bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
         size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>1</span> 
       </p>
      </td>
      <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
         windowtext 
         1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
         bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
         size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>Name
         1</span></p>
      </td>
      <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
          windowtext 
          1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
       <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin 
          bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
          size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>Name
          2</span></p>
       </td>
       <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
           windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 
           5.4pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>This is 
           some text</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 
            5.4pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp; 
           </span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp; 
           </span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border- 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
           normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times 
           New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border- 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt;
            padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
        <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
           normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times 
           New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the CSS code that I have tried.  Below is the most recent version, but I saw in other posts that the !important should let me override the inline styles.  In this example, I have both width and style modifications because the HTML from Word has both, but I have tried just one and the other.

```
body {
    font-family: "Arial";
}

table {
    width=100% !important;
}
td[style]:nth-child(1) {
    width=5% !important;
    style='width:5%;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border- 
               top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt' !important>
}
td[style]:nth-child(2) {
    width=10% !important;
    style='width:10%;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border- 
               top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt' !important>
}
td[style]:nth-child(3) {
    width=10% !important;
    style='width:10%;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border- 
               top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt' !important>
}
td[style]:nth-child(4) {
    width=75% !important;
    style='width:79%;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-            
               top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt' !important>
}
```

I am expecting the output of the page to have the tables all be a certain percentage of the web page and also define the percentages of the columns.  For example, the table will be 100%, column 1 will be 5%, column 1 will be 10%, column 1 will be 10%, and column 4 will be 75%,

Comment: Inline styles like `<td width=96 style="width:1.0in" />` are more important/will overwrite css styles. So removing inline styles and adding all styles in a css stylesheet is best practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS you posted is invalid. Fix it up and it should behave as expected.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
}

table {
  width: 100% !important;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 5% !important;
  border: solid windowtext 1pt;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt !important;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10% !important;
  border: solid windowtext 1pt;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt !important;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10% !important;
  border: solid windowtext 1pt;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt !important;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 75% !important;
  border: solid windowtext 1pt;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt !important;
}
```

```html
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border-collapse:collapse'>
  <tr>
    <td width=67 valign=top style='width:.7in;border:solid 
         windowtext 
         1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
         bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
         size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>1</span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
         windowtext 
         1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
         bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
         size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>Name
         1</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
          windowtext 
          1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin 
          bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
          size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>Name
          2</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
           windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 
           5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>This is 
           some text</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 
            5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp; 
           </span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height: normal'><span style='font- 
           size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp; 
           </span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border- 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin- 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
           normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times 
           New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=96 valign=top style='width:1.0in;border- 
            top:none;border-left:none;
            border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid 
            windowtext 1.0pt;
            padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0in;margin 
           bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
           normal'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times 
           New Roman","serif"'>&nbsp;</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```